# Jenkins-sonar build error

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonar-runner

I am getting the below error logs while configuring my job on `jenkins` with `sonar`:

> [ERROR] SonarQube server [http://wkwmorablrd01:9000] can not be
>   reached [INFO] LNG ...............................................
>   FAILURE [17.172s] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project extension: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail
>   to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url
>   [http://wkwmorablrd01:9000/batch/index] is not valid: [404] -> [Help
>   1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the
>   build with the command [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :extension

Could you please help me ?

Regards,
Shwetha

Comment: Also when i logged into the url: http://wkwmorablrd01:9000/ and saw I am getting "This site can’t be reached". Could you please also let me know how to bring the sonar instance up?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check which version of SonarQube your Jenkins is using.
The [6.5 version of SonarQube (or more) is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46837669/6309).

But first, do check your SonarQube server is correctly configured:
"[Installing the Server](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server)"

And make sure you don't have HTTP(S)_PROXY environment variables that would make your connection foes to a proxy while your server might need to be accessed *without* a proxy (if on the same LAN)

Comment: I am unable to bring up the sonar instance to check the version and other specifications. Can you please help?

Comment: @shwethavr Contact your SonarQube admin first: he/she will be able to confirm the server is available.

Comment: I am using jenkins 1.585 version with 2.1 version of sonar scanner plugin which is compatible as per https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins

Comment: I myself am the admin but do not know about the set up because I have newly joined and the admin has left the company:(

Comment: Sonar version is 5.0 and jenkins version is 1.585 with sonar scanner plugin 2.1 version. Are these compatible?